# RLS path calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax, row-level-security

I am pretty new to RLS and have been trying to implement it in a certain way.

[image]

My table above is a sample. I am trying to create RLS here based on the levels. Normally I can create 3 roles for 3 levels where,
Level 1 is regular employees
Level 2 is supervisor of employees
Level 3 is the manager/head of the building (based on the BuildingID)

I am trying to create RLS where the manager (Level 3) will be able to see the data for people below them by filtering through. For example when the manager of BuildingID='233' logs in, they can filter through the report to see people they are assigned to.

[image]

It would be clickable in the filter pane. However, I am more used to on doing DAX calculations when the manager ID is on a different column and this seems to be a new scenario. I have tried a couple of methods and so far have not been successful. Any kind of help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I could only advise you review something like this to see if you can use the comparable logic in your scenario https://radacad.com/dynamic-row-level-security-with-organizational-hierarchy-power-bi